# Why does my custom Swing component repaint faster when I move the mouse? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, mouse, repaint

I am trying to make a 2D game with Java and Swing, and the window refreshes too slow.  But if I move the mouse or press keys, the window refreshes as fast as it should!

Here is a GIF showing how the window refreshes quickly only when I move the mouse.

[image]

Why does the window refresh slowly like that?  Why does the mouse and keyboard affect its refresh rate?  How, if possible, do I make it refresh quickly all the time?

### Background Info

I use a [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to update the game state every 1/25 seconds, after which it calls [repaint()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint(long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) on the game panel to redraw the scene.

I understand that a Timer might not always delay for exactly 1/25 of a second.

I also understand that calling repaint() just requests the window to be repainted ASAP and does not repaint the window immediately.

My graphics card does not support OpenGL 2+ or hardware accelerated 3D graphics, which is why I am not using libgdx or JME for game development.

### System Info

- Operating system: Linux Mint 19 Tara
- JDK version: OpenJDK 11.0.4
- Graphics card: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ

### Research

[This Stack Overflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291814/java-swing-or-awt-repaint-frequency) describes the same problem I have, but the author reportedly solved the issue by calling repaint() repeatedly on a separate timer.  I tried this, and it *does make the window refresh somewhat faster*, but even then it is a slower than I want.  In this case, wiggling the mouse on the window *still improves the refresh rate*.  Therefore, it seems like that post did not truly solve the issue.

[Another Stack Overflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688387/java-swing-graphics-stutter) also encountered the issue, but they use a continuous while-loop instead of a Timer for their game loop.  Apparently, this user solved the problem by using Thread.sleep() in their while loop.  However, my code accomplishes the delay using a Timer, so I do not know how Thread.sleep() could solve my problem, or even where I would put it.

I've read through [Painting with AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to figure out whether I just misunderstood the concept of repainting, but nothing in that document elucidates the issue for me.  I call repaint() whenever the game updates, and the window only refreshes quickly when mouse or keyboard input is happening.

I have searched the web for several days now trying to find an answer, but nothing seems to help!

### Code

```java
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class Game {
        public static final int screenWidth = 160;
        public static final int screenHeight = 140;

        /**
         * Create and show the GUI.
         */
        private static void createAndShowGUI() {
                /* Create the GUI. */
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new GamePanel());
                frame.pack();

                /* Show the GUI. */
                frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        /**
         * Run the game.
         *
         * @param args  the list of command-line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                /* Schedule the GUI to be created on the EDT. */
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
        }

}

/**
 * A GamePanel widget updates and shows the game scene.
 */
class GamePanel extends JPanel {
        private Square square;

        /**
         * Create a game panel and start its update-and-draw cycle
         */
        public GamePanel() {
                super();

                /* Set the size of the game screen. */
                setPreferredSize(
                        new Dimension(
                                Game.screenWidth,
                                Game.screenHeight));

                /* Create the square in the game world. */
                square = new Square(0, 0, 32, 32, Square.Direction.LEFT);

                /* Update the scene every 40 milliseconds. */
                Timer timer = new Timer(40, (e) -> updateScene());
                timer.start();
        }

        /**
         * Paint the game scene using a graphics context.
         *
         * @param g  the graphics context
         */
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                /* Clear the screen. */
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.screenWidth, Game.screenHeight);

                /* Draw all objects in the scene. */
                square.draw(g);
        }

        /**
         * Update the game state.
         */
        private void updateScene() {
                /* Update all objects in the scene. */
                square.update();

                /* Request the scene to be repainted. */
                repaint();
        }

}

/**
 * A Square is a game object which looks like a square.
 */
class Square {
        public static enum Direction { LEFT, RIGHT };

        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private Direction direction;

        /**
         * Create a square game object.
         *
         * @param x          the square's x position
         * @param y          the square's y position
         * @param width      the square's width (in pixels)
         * @param height     the square's height (in pixels)
         * @param direction  the square's direction of movement
         */
        public Square(int x,
                      int y,
                      int width,
                      int height,
                      Direction direction) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                this.direction = direction;
        }

        /**
         * Draw the square using a graphics context.
         *
         * @param g  the graphics context
         */
        public void draw(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
        }

        /**
         * Update the square's state.
         *
         * The square slides horizontally
         * until it reaches the edge of the screen,
         * at which point it begins sliding in the
         * opposite direction.
         *
         * This should be called once per frame.
         */
        public void update() {
                if (direction == Direction.LEFT) {
                        x--;

                        if (x <= 0) {
                                direction = Direction.RIGHT;
                        }
                } else if (direction == Direction.RIGHT) {
                        x++;

                        if (x + width >= Game.screenWidth) {
                                direction = Direction.LEFT;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your Timer does not execute on the edt, that might be the problem. Can you change it to  `Timer timer = new Timer(40, (e) -> { SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> updateScene()); } );` and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @k5_ A Swing timer is always executed in EDT by default. I do not think using `invokeLater` will help.

Comment: @k5_ Thanks for the reply!  I implemented your suggestion but the problem is still there.  From what I can tell, it looks like nothing changed.

Comment: Would also suggest grabbing a simple JavaFX example and seeing if that has the same issue

Comment: This is a case where calling [`paintImmediately`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately-int-int-int-int-) may be justified. You can avoid runaway resource consumption by calling `setCoalesce(true)` on the timer; as you already know, you should consider the truly elapsed time in `update` anyway. In such a setup, you may even invoke [`setIgnoreRepaint(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setIgnoreRepaint-boolean-) on the component when starting the animation as you know there will be updates in reasonable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you probably cannot solve your issue by [enabling OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41002553/6579265), since your gpu does not support it, a possible silly workaround could be to fire a kind of event manually in each timer's iteration.

```
/* Update the scene every 40 milliseconds. */
final Robot robot = new Robot();
Timer timer = new Timer(40, (e) -> {
    robot.mouseRelease(0); //some event
    updateScene();
});
timer.start();
```

(And the only place you can `Thread.sleep()` in a Swing Application is inside a [SwingWorker's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) `doInBackground` method. If you call it in EDT the whole GUI will freeze since events cannot take place.)

Comment: Your solution works as long as I have the game in focus, but when I switch to another window it simulates the keypresses there too (a bunch of 0s fill up any textbox I select).  I need a cleaner solution.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @user12071097 You could experiment with this. I updated my post. :)

Comment: Oh hey! I looked at that sun.java2d.opengl answer you linked to, and it worked!  Maybe the default rendering backend just doesn't refresh as often as OpenGL.  I added the -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true to my java invocation and everything runs smooth now.  If you add the details to your answer, I will accept it :-)

Comment: @user12071097 I do not think there are any details to add related to `OpenGL`. I mean, it is `OpenGL`... plus it is explained in the link already. :) Glad that you solved it though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The solution is quite simple. Call `revalidate()` immediately after you call `repaint()`:

```
private void updateScene() {
            /* Update all objects in the scene. */
            square.update();

            /* Request the scene to be repainted. */
            repaint();

            revalidate(); // <-- this will now repaint as fast as you wanted it to
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at this, and oddly enough if I use a JLabel with an ImageIcon, it seems to solve the problem.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

class Game {
        public static final int screenWidth = 160;
        public static final int screenHeight = 140;
        /**
         * Create and show the GUI.
         */
        private static void createAndShowGUI() {
                /* Create the GUI. */
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();
                
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel.getComponent());
                frame.pack();
                /* Show the GUI. */
                frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        /**
         * Run the game.
         *
         * @param args  the list of command-line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                /* Schedule the GUI to be created on the EDT. */
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
        }

}

/**
 * A GamePanel widget updates and shows the game scene.
 */
class GamePanel{
        private Square square;
        final BufferedImage img;
        JLabel label;
        /**
         * Create a game panel and start its update-and-draw cycle
         */
        public GamePanel() {
                img = new BufferedImage(Game.screenWidth, Game.screenHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                square = new Square(0, 0, 32, 32, Square.Direction.LEFT);
                paintComponent();
                label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
                
                /* Update the scene every 40 milliseconds. */
                Timer timer = new Timer(40, (e) -> updateScene());
                timer.start();
        }

        /**
         * Paint the game scene using a graphics context.
         *
         * @param g  the graphics context
         */
        protected void paintComponent() {
            Graphics g = img.getGraphics();

            /* Clear the screen. */
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.screenWidth, Game.screenHeight);

            /* Draw all objects in the scene. */
            square.draw(g);
        }

        /**
         * Update the game state.
         */
        private void updateScene() {
                /* Update all objects in the scene. */
                square.update();
                paintComponent();
                //label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                label.repaint();
        }
        public JLabel getComponent(){
            return label;
        }

}

/**
 * A Square is a game object which looks like a square.
 */
class Square {
        public static enum Direction { LEFT, RIGHT };

        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private Direction direction;

        /**
         * Create a square game object.
         *
         * @param x          the square's x position
         * @param y          the square's y position
         * @param width      the square's width (in pixels)
         * @param height     the square's height (in pixels)
         * @param direction  the square's direction of movement
         */
        public Square(int x,
                      int y,
                      int width,
                      int height,
                      Direction direction) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                this.direction = direction;
        }

        /**
         * Draw the square using a graphics context.
         *
         * @param g  the graphics context
         */
        public void draw(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
        }

        /**
         * Update the square's state.
         *
         * The square slides horizontally
         * until it reaches the edge of the screen,
         * at which point it begins sliding in the
         * opposite direction.
         *
         * This should be called once per frame.
         */
        public void update() {
                if (direction == Direction.LEFT) {
                        x--;

                        if (x <= 0) {
                                direction = Direction.RIGHT;
                        }
                } else if (direction == Direction.RIGHT) {
                        x++;

                        if (x + width >= Game.screenWidth) {
                                direction = Direction.LEFT;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

All I did is create a BufferedImage that is used for the JLabel image icon and it updates smoothly.